# Can the ClassTableInheritance plugin for Sequel be configured to store something other than the model name as the key?

Tags: ruby, orm, sequel, class-table-inheritance

I am using the [class_table_inheritance Sequel plugin](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-plugins/classes/Sequel/Plugins/ClassTableInheritance.html) for my project and I have the following models:

```
class Account < Sequel::Model
  plugin :class_table_inheritance
end

class TwitterAccount < Account; end
class FacebookAccount < Account; end
class GoogleAccount < Account; end
```

I would prefer to setup a column called 'account_type' in my Account table that is an enum with the possible values 'Twitter', 'Facebook' and 'Google' to identify what type an account is.

I don't like the idea of a column in my table that is tied to the name of my model classes. It directly ties me to the ORM I am using and prevents changing the model names.

Is there any way to provide to the class_table_inheritance plugin a key map of symbols to class name symbols just like there is the ability to provide a table map of class name symbols to table name symbols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the `class_table_inheritance` plugin doesn't support such a feature (unlike the `single_table_inheritance` plugin).  It shouldn't be difficult to add support for such a feature, I'll see if I can work on that soon.

Comment: I see you already implemented this feature in a commit https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/commit/7eb78fe6a6b4a6974040e47f659bef3b13bf485c many thanks!